# Возврат множества List

Tags: c#, list

Есть 2 множества `List` с разными типами данных:

```
class BookInfo
{
    int id;
    string name;
    string title;
    string desc;
    string img;
}

class Book
{
    int id;
}

List<BookInfo> list1;
List<Book> list2;
```

В `list1` содержится полная информация обо всех книгах библиотеки, а в `list2` - имеющиеся в наличии. Нужно получить множество `BookInfo`, которое будет содержать инфу только о имеющихся книгах, т.е. получить пересечение множеств.

Что-то перебираю методы `List` и пока не удалось найти нужный. Подскажите плз как это делается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

по-моему `List<Book> list2;` можно с лёгкостью заменить на `List<int> list2;`

тогда запрос сведётся к простому выражению:

```
list1.Where(book => list2.Contains(book.id));
```

Comment: чёрт) это то что мне нужно) Вообще мой вариант тоже верно работал, просто я искал по одному ключу, а у меня их два, из-за чего записей и получалось больше, вот и подумал что неверно делаю). Кстати сделал глупый отдельный класс, потому что не догадался до подобной выборки)
И получилось вот так:
GameIds.Join(GamesInfo.Where(x => x.LocId == SiteInfo.Localization).ToList(), x => x.Id, y => y.AppId, (x, y) => y).ToList();
Заюзаю Ваш вариант, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, ваша структура данных неверна. Она чересчур похожа на какую-то базу данных, где все типы плоские, а соответствие делается при помощи join'ов.

Зачем вам `id` в `BookInfo`? Чтобы иметь ссылку на книгу, держите там таки книгу, а не её для последующего поиска по нему.

Ваш класс должен выглядеть так:

```
class BookInfo
{
 Book book;
 string name;
 string title;
 string desc;
 string img;
}
```

Поскольку `list2` используется как фильтр, его надо из `List<Book>` превратить в структуру данных, поддерживающую быстрый lookup, например, `HashSet<Book>`.

Тогда ваш код будет таким: `list1.Select(bi => bi.book).Where(list2.Contains)`, если нужно выбрать `Book`.

Если выбрать нужно `BookInfo`, код тогда соответственно `list1.Where(bi => list2.Contains(bi.book))`.

Comment: пример был взят для наглядности, структура порядком сложнее и связь идёт 1:N. поэтому хранить полную инфу целесообразней в отдельном листе.

Comment: @t0di: не вижу целесообразности, если честно. Ссылка не стоит практически ничего, плюс позволяет избегать join'ов. Вы наверное много с таблицами работали прежде?

Answer (score 0):

Способ за `O(n)`:

```
//Создаем хэш-табличку, чтобы уметь получать BookInfo по Id за O(1)
Dictionary<int, BookInfo> dic = list1.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x);

//Проходимся по списку и для каждого id получаем соответствующий BookInfo из dic.
List<BookInfo> result = list2.Select(x => dic[x.id]).ToList();
```

Если время совсем не критично, используйте [решение Spectre](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/175994#175997) за O(n^2).